# how to plot different graphs on the same QChart in Qt

Tags: qt

I am trying to plot a different graph on QChart when i click on a button. That's what I've tried till now:

```
QChart *charts = new QChart();
charts->legend()->hide();
charts->createDefaultAxes();
std::string name = "Channel";
charts->setTitle(QString::fromStdString(name));

QChartView *chartView_1 = new QChartView(charts);
chartView_1->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);

QGridLayout *gridLayout_1 = new QGridLayout(ui->widget);
gridLayout_1->addWidget(chartView_1,0,0);
```

this is written in the constructor

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

    QScatterSeries *series_1 = new QScatterSeries();
    for(int k = 0; k < 127; k++){
        series_1->append(k + (k/2),k);
        series_1->setMarkerSize(4.0);
    }

    QChart *charts = new QChart();
    charts->addSeries(series_1);

    QChartView *chartView_1 = new QChartView(charts);
    chartView_1->repaint();

    QGridLayout *gridLayout_1 = new QGridLayout(ui->widget);
    gridLayout_1->addWidget(chartView_1,0,0);
}
```

and this one in the button function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I just added:

```
gridLayout_1->deleteLater();
```

and it worked